# Boot drive is incorrect one

Tags: windows, boot, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two instances of Windows Vista on boot up after failed clean install](https://superuser.com/questions/304164/two-instances-of-windows-vista-on-boot-up-after-failed-clean-install)

I have several hard drives installed. I normally use c: as my boot drive and a much larger drive (h:) for storing most of my files. I found a subfolder in my c:windows folder named windows after a failed reinstall of Vista. Upon inspection I determined it to be older than the c:windows folder and therefore it must be the older, working version of the boot. I renamed the c:windows folder to c:windows.bad and moved the sub windows to the c: root directory. I also copied it to the h: drive. Now MSCONFIG reports that the copy that is booting is the h: copy. How can I change it back to the c: copy and can I delete the c:windows.bad file set?

Comment: Haven't you already [asked this](http://superuser.com/questions/304164/two-instances-of-windows-vista-on-boot-up-after-failed-clean-install)? If you've updated information then please go edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can specify which drive you want to boot from in the BIOS. Though it would be best to just start from scratch and reinstall Vista correctly.